# System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '10

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have add an Image resource for the wpf project am making by:

`right-click on the Project -> Properties -> Resources -> Images -> From Existing -> ClientBackGround.png`

and I made it background for the main window :

```
<Window x:Class="Illuminate_AutoPatcher.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="1000" Height="750" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/ClientBackground.png"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Margin="766,613,0,0" Height="124" >
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

but it's not working it's keep throwing this anoying error `System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '10` , how I supposed to fix it, so I use static resources that's build with the project?

Comment: Check the inner exception.

Comment: I think you'd rather change the `siteoforigin` to `application` and have the image's build action set to `Resource`.

Comment: the inner exception is : `{"Could not find a part of the path 'D:\\CProgramming\\Illuminate AutoPatcher\\Illuminate AutoPatcher\\bin\\Debug\\Resources\\ClientBackground.png'."}`

Answer (score 8):

@HighCore is right, using *application* solves your issue in the given scenario

```
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/ClientBackground.png"/>
```

You still can use *siteoforigin*. For that you have to set the image property

**Copy to Output Directory** to "***Copy always***"

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494.aspx#Site_of_Origin_Files)